# Dex file methods count using analyze apk

Tags: android, methods, dex, android-multidex

I've used analyze apk option from android studio.
It tells like below:
**This dex file defines 8355 classes with 54,392 methods, and references 65,276 methods.**

I know that the referenced method count should not exceed 65,535 and I'm on border like 65,276.

What's meant by 54,392 methods from 8355 classes?
I just want to know about whats meant to **This dex file defines 8355 classes with 54,392 methods**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your compiled source consists of 8355 .class files defining 54,392 methods total, however the app may also reference methods from dynamically linked shared libraries and that is why the **referenced** method count is higher than the **'with'** method count.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whats are all the dynamic linked libraries here? Dependent .so files of my app?

Comment: Mostly I think it's the framework methods that are stubbed in android SDK jar, but it also might be AIDL stubs, basically everything that gets called from your code but is not explicitly defined within your source

Answer (score 0):

The **Referenced Methods** column counts all methods that are referenced by the DEX file. This typically includes methods defined in your code, dependency libraries, and methods defined in standard Java and Android packages that the code uses—these are the methods counted toward the 64k method limit in each DEX file. The **Defined Methods** column counts only the methods that are defined in one of your DEX files, so this number is a subset of **Referenced Methods**. Note that when you package a dependency in your APK, the methods defined in the dependency add to both method counts.

Visit https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html